# Critera for launch

Tags: discussion

There are many sites [still in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta). Will Skeptics.SE have to reach [these critera](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics) for 90 conceiving days to launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Cartaino already covered [this on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76338/what-are-the-success-criteria-for-an-area-51-beta-site/76392#76392):

> A site will stay in beta for at least 90 days. After 90 days, it becomes eligible for graduation as a full site. A site will graduate when it has:
>
> 1. Established a critical mass of "experts" so that there is a reasonable expectation that your question will be answered (+90% according to the [Area 51 analytics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics)).
> 2. Reached a level of maturity to become a self-sustaining, community-moderated site (+10 users with +2,000 rep, 5 users with +3,000 rep).
> 3. Reach a critical mass of users where the traffic indicates strong, sustainable growth.
>
> If the site has not reached these goals by 90 days in beta, it can remain a beta site as long as it continues to show steady progress. But if the beta site is showing a general, unrecoverable, downward trend, [it may be closed as inviable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/).

The rationale is explained in [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), on the Stack Overflow blog.

Answer (score 1):

The SE team has often said, that they only launch sites "when they are ready", even if that takes longer than 90 days. As long as a site is showing signs of growth and improvement, it is in no danger of being closed.

So we should not worry about these statistics and just try to create an interesting site that will attract more skeptics and experts in various areas of pseudoscience.